# long table latex

Tags: latex, longtable

[image]

I want to create a table as depicted in the picture. I have used the following code
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LCL}

```
Pollutant      & Description and sources  & Health and environment effects \\
\hline
SO$_2$ & SO$_2$ is formed by oxidation of sulphur (S), mainly through combustion of fuels containing S. The electricity generation sector is the most important source of SO$_2$. SO$_2$ also can contribute to the formation of secondary sulphate particles in the atmosphere. & SO$_2$ aggravates asthma and can reduce lung function and inflame the respiratory tract. It can cause headache, general discomfort and anxiety. SO$_2$ contributes to acid deposition, the impacts of which can be significant, causing damage to forests and ecosystems in rivers and lakes. \\
\hline
Nitrogen oxides (NO$_x$). & NO$_x$ is emitted during fuel combustion e.g. from industrial facilities and the road transport sector. NO$_x$ is a group of gases comprising nitrogen monoxide (NO) and nitrogen dioxide (NO$_2$). NO makes up the majority of NO$_x$ emissions. NO$_x$ contributes to the formation of ozone and particulate matter. & NO$_2$ is associated with adverse effects on health: it can affect the liver, lung, spleen and blood. It can also aggravate lung diseases leading to respiratory symptoms and increased susceptibility to respiratory infection. As with SO$_2$, NO$_x$ contributes to acid deposition but also to eutrophication of soil and water. \\
\hline
```

\end{tabulary}
\end{document}

They don't look very nice with the command above. What should I do to make it look more like the one in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can color table elements with the `colortbl` package and approximate the green background with the `color` package, also, just add a few formatting commands to play with font sizes and weights, as well as column widths used by `tabulary`, cf. [documentation](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/tabulary/tabulary.pdf).

The following should give you more or less the desired result:

```
\usepackage{tabulary, color, colortbl}
\definecolor{MyGreen}{rgb}{0.5,0.7,0.4}

\tymin=70pt

\begin{document}

\begin{tabulary}{500pt}{LLL}
\hline
\rowcolor{MyGreen}
\bf Pollutant & \bf Description and sources & \bf Health and environment effects \\[5pt]
\hline
\small \bf Sulphur dioxide (SO$_2$) & \small SO$_2$ is formed by oxidation of sulphur (S), mainly through combustion of fuels containing S. The electricity generation sector is the most important source of SO$_2$. SO$_2$ also can contribute to the formation of secondary sulphate particles in the atmosphere. & \small SO$_2$ aggravates asthma and can reduce lung function and inflame the respiratory tract. It can cause headache, general discomfort and anxiety. SO$_2$ contributes to acid deposition, the impacts of which can be significant, causing damage to forests and ecosystems in rivers and lakes. \\
\arrayrulecolor{MyGreen}
\hline
\small \bf Nitrogen oxides (NO$_x$) & \small NO$_x$ is emitted during fuel combustion e.g. from industrial facilities and the road transport sector. NO$_x$ is a group of gases comprising nitrogen monoxide (NO) and nitrogen dioxide (NO$_2$). NO makes up the majority of NO$_x$ emissions. NO$_x$ contributes to the formation of ozone and particulate matter. & \small NO$_2$ is associated with adverse effects on health: it can affect the liver, lung, spleen and blood. It can also aggravate lung diseases leading to respiratory symptoms and increased susceptibility to respiratory infection. As with SO$_2$, NO$_x$ contributes to acid deposition but also to eutrophication of soil and water. \\
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```